# What is happening here?

Tags: url, web, cgi

http://www.google.se/search?Key1=Value1&Key2=Value2

Can i get some technical idea about this link??

I am aware of these.
The first "http://" describes the server using,
"www.google.se" is the server name.

My questions include:
is "search" an CGI script in servers root folder? If so why it doesn't have a .cgi extension?
If n't What is it exactly, and can i get any sample script of search(if it is an script).

Comment: Note that the "http://" part denotes the high level protocol used to retrieve the given URI. You should probably have a little more reading  networks, computer architecture, and other basic things, before you delve into this stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A web server can respond to any URL in any way it pleases, without necessarily having a CGI script at a particular location in a filesystem.

It's possible to write a web server with the following hypothetical method:

```
def GET(host, path, query):
    if path == "/hello":
        print "Hello, world"
    elif path == "/search":
        perform_search(query)
```

There is no requirement for a CGI script to exist anywhere.

Comment: @Gokul: He is suggesting that the "thing" handling the URL `http://www.google.se/search?Key1=Value1&Key2=Value2` could be anything and does not need to correspond to a file or script or path or whatever. Could well be that the server puts together a response based on the number of characters in the URL, and nothing more. You might enjoy a good read about how [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP) works.

Answer (score 0):

This is called URL rewriting. It is done within the web server and can involve sending requests to a single file (for example index.php or cgi for that matter) without you seeing it.

In this particular example google **might** send all requests that start with "/search" to search.php and although search.php will certainly be aware that the URI is search?Key1=Value1&Key2=Value2 you will see what you see exactly in your address bar.

Comment: I don't think you have notice these. My questions include: is "search" an CGI script in servers root folder? If so why it doesn't have a .cgi extension? If n't What is it exactly, and can i get any sample script of search(if it is an script).

Comment: My answer is right there. If you can't make a sense of it, it means you're not ready for the truth yet. Sorry to say that.

Comment: With all due respect, Still didn't got any answer for my question.. And from your answer how the google sends all the requests which start with /search to search.php. This is the part i am missing!!!